# Flutter http stuck

Tags: json, flutter, http

I am sending an API request to return a list of widgets. But it doesn't return anything. I created a model, http service, and a Future builder to return.
my code:
my services file:

> service.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import '../models/models.dart';

    class CardsService {
      final String url = "xxx.com/xx.php";
    
      
    
        Future<List<Cards>> getCards() async {
            Response res = await get(url);
        
            if (res.statusCode == 200) {
              List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(res.body);
        
              List<Cards> card = body
                  .map(
                    (dynamic item) => Cards.fromJson(item),
                  )
                  .toList();
        
              return card;
            } else {
              throw "Can't get Cards.";
            }
          }
        }
```

my model file:

> model.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Cards {
  final String country;
  final String type;
  final int value;
  final String percentage;
  final String sign;

  Cards(
      {
      @required this.country,
      @required this.type,
      @required this.value,
      @required this.percentage,
      @required this.sign
      }
      );

  factory Cards.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Cards(
      country: json['country'] as String,
      type: json['type'] as String,
      value: json['value'] as int,
      percentage: json['percentage'] as String,
      sign: json['sign'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

my main file:

> main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/models.dart';
import '../services/cards.dart';


class CardsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final CardsService cardsService = CardsService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Posts"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: cardsService.getCards(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Cards>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Cards> cards = snapshot.data;
            return ListView(
              children: cards
                  .map(
                    (Cards cards) => ListTile(
                      title: Text(cards.value.toString()),
                      subtitle: Text("${cards.sign}"),
                      onTap:null ,
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but it returns nothing than the CircularProgressIndicator(){i waited so much but it did not show anything, no error and I ran flutter doctor. Everything is ok}), this is my JSON:

```
  {
    "country": "lebanon",
    "type": "sell",
    "value": "8100",
    "updated": "الأحد ٢٩ - نوفمبر - ٢٠٢٠   ٠٧:٣٣ مساءً",
    "percentage": "0.3%",
    "sign": "decreased"
  },
  {
    "country": "lebanon",
    "type": "buy",
    "value": "8175",
    "updated": "الأحد ٢٩ - نوفمبر - ٢٠٢٠   ٠٧:٣٣ مساءً",
    "percentage": "0%",
    "sign": "increased"
  },
  {
    "country": "syria",
    "type": "sell",
    "value": "2560",
    "updated": "اليوم",
    "percentage": "1%",
    "sign": "decreased"
  },
  {
    "country": "syria",
    "type": "buy",
    "value": "2590",
    "updated": "اليوم",
    "percentage": "1%",
    "sign": "decreased"
  }
]
```

Comment: print out `card` in `getCards`. What you get?

Comment: while using async/await it is recommended to wrap them inside a try/catch. so, wrap your `await get(url)` inside a try/catch then print the response or print the error inside catch.

Comment: i will do what you both suggested, and then response to you

Comment: @Mahdi-Jafaree I wrapped it in catch-throw, but it didn't catch anything, and when I printed the response body, I got normal JSON with no errors

Comment: i figured out that the problem is from these lines of code:  List<Cards> card = body
          .map(
            (dynamic item) => Cards.fromJson(item),
          )
          .toList();
  
        return card;

Comment: but how can I solve it?'

Comment: @evarakiller in `map(dynamic item)` you are returning a dynamic which can be string, custome model, int and etc but `Cards.fromJson(item)` accespts `Map<String,dynamic` so a dynamic is not a subtype of a specific type. try casting dynamic as `Map<String, dynamic>` in map function and share the result.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing really. The http calls are made, some return, but sometimes one gets stuck and throws timeout exception. I have the same application written already in Android native(java + kotlin) using Retrofit, and this never happens!